# Replace elements of particular axis index in n-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given an n-dimensional numpy array. Now an axis and corresponding index is given. All elements in that particular axis-index should be replaced by given value.
Example of an three-dimensional array:

```
>>a = np.ones((2,2,2))
array([[[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]],

        [[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]]])
```

Given axis=1, index=0. All elements in this axis-index needs to be zero.

```
>>a
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.]]])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `swapaxes`:

```
a.swapaxes(0, axis)[index] = value
```

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((2,3,4))
>>> a.swapaxes(0, 1)[2] = 3
>>> a
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3.]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do `a[:,0,:] = 0` and you get your output, where in `a[:,0,:]` you select index = 0 of the axis=1 and you set the value to 0 over all the other axis

Comment: The axis and index are calculated by a program in my case. For your method to work, one needs to know them beforehand.